# Unable to send POST parameters with mix of MultiPartFile to Rest Service using spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have Spring Rest service defined as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mobilebuild", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StringWrapper buildApp(@RequestParam("projectName") String projectName, @RequestParam("appId") String projectId, @RequestParam("version") String version, @RequestParam("app") MultipartFile file) {
        //Process to build app
        return WMUtils.SUCCESS_RESPONSE;
    }
```

From client side i am using rest template as follows

```
final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName(CommonConstants.UTF8)));
messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());
messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(messageConverters);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
 //Post Parameters
parts.add("projectName", "FirstProject");
parts.add("appId", "app12345");
parts.add("version", "1.0");   
// MultipartFile
parts.add("app", new FileSystemResource(tempFilesStorageManager.getFilePath("/tmp/app.zip")));  

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Cookie", auth);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

String url = "http://localhost:8080/AppManager/services/mobilebuild";

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap>(parts, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = template.postForEntity(endpointAddress, requestEntity, String.class);
String response = responseEntity.getBody();
```

I am unable to read the request parameters from controller (server): getting the following error

**Error:** request parameter `projectName` is not present in the request.

So please suggest me the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-) of `HttpEntity` , the first parameter is request body and second one is request headers, but your client is sending request parameters inside request body and your controller is expecting them as `@RequestParam`, hence the error.

So either change your client to send the request parameters in the end point address URL to match your server side as `...projectName=FirstProject&appId= app12345&version=1.0....`

Or encapsulate all your `@RequestParam` fields inside a single DTO class and add `@RequestBody` annotation on server side if your client wants to send in request body.